# Overriding touchesBegan in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am overriding:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent)
```

in Swift.

I am wondering, is this correct for getting one touch point:

```
var touchPoint: CGPoint! = event.touchesForView(self)?.anyObject()?.locationInView(self)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of iOS 8.3, `touchesBegan` takes a `touches` parameter which is a `Set<NSObject>`. It's now `Set<UITouch>`. So, you would:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let point = touches.first?.location(in: view) else { return }

    // use `point` here
}
```

---

In previous iOS versions, `touchesBegan` was defined as a `NSSet` parameter, as outlined in the question, so you would:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    if let touch = touches.anyObject() as? UITouch {
        let touchPoint = touch.locationInView(view)
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This no longer compiles, the following post is more up to date and explains the best way of implementing touchesBegan: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28771896/overriding-method-with-selector-touchesbeganwithevent-has-incompatible-type

Comment: The question obviously predated iOS 8.3 and explicitly specified the `NSSet` parameter used in earlier iOS versions, but for the sake of future readers, I've updated it accordingly. Thanks.