# Overriding method with selector 'touchesBegan:withEvent:' has incompatible type '(NSSet, UIEvent) -> ()'

Tags: ios, swift, overriding

Xcode 6.3.  Within a class implementing UITextFieldDelegate protocol, I would like to override touchesBegan() method to possibly hide the keyboard.  If I avoid a compiler error in the function spec, then there is a complier error trying to read the "touch" from the Set or NSSet, or else the   super.touchesBegan(touches , withEvent:event) throws an error.  One of these combinations compiled in Xcode 6.2!  (So where is documentation to Swift "Set" and how to get an element from one?)

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) { 
    // Hiding the Keyboard when the User Taps the Background
        if let touch =  touches.anyObject() as? UITouch {
            if nameTF.isFirstResponder() && touch.view != nameTF {
                nameTF.resignFirstResponder();
            }
        }
        super.touchesBegan(touches , withEvent:event)
    }
```

Try:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) or
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent)
```

Compiler error:
Overriding method with selector 'touchesBegan:withEvent:' has incompatible type '(NSSet, UIEvent) -> ()'
and

```
super.touchesBegan(touches , withEvent:event)
```

also complains

'NSSet' is not implicitly convertible to 'Set'; did you mean to use 'as' to explicitly convert?

Try:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<AnyObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent)
```

Compiler error:
 Type 'AnyObject' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'

Try:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent)
```

Compiler error at

```
if let touch = touches.anyObject() as? UITouch
```

'Set' does not have a member named 'anyObject' BUT the function spec and call to super() are OK!

Try:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet<AnyObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) -> () or
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent)
```

Compiler error:
Cannot specialize non-generic type 'NSSet'

Answer (score 161, accepted):

**Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3)** introduced a native `Set` type that bridges
with `NSSet`. This is mentioned in the [Swift blog](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=22) and in the
[Xcode 6.3 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html), <strike>but apparently not yet added to the official documentation</strike> (update: As [Ahmad Ghadiri noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29549529/1187415), it *is* documented now).

The `UIResponder` method is now declared as

```
func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent)
```

and you can override it like this:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {
        // ...
    }
    super.touchesBegan(touches , withEvent:event)
}
```

**Update for Swift 2 (Xcode 7):** (Compare [Override func error in Swift 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30892254/override-func-error-in-swift-2))

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        // ...
    }
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent:event)
}
```

**Update for Swift 3:**

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        // ...
    }
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Martin R, All I had to do was change my NSSet to Set<NSObject> and my code is functioning.

Comment: Hi @Martin Why  `super.touchesBegan(touches , withEvent:event)` is need? I am still not understand Swift very well.

Comment: I feel like it needs to be this: super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent:event!) for xCode 7.2

Comment: @EugeneGordin: Why do you think so? The last method still compiles with Xcode 7.2.

Comment: it was complaining for me...value of optional type not unwrapped

Comment: @ZigiiWong because it's the superclass that **eventually** communicates/transfer the `touch`, `event` and makes the UI change. Things won't be managed properly....

Answer (score 10):

With xCode 7 and swift 2.0, use following code:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    if let touch =  touches.first{
        print("\(touch)")
    }
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    if let touch = touches.first{
        print("\(touch)")
    }
    super.touchesEnded(touches, withEvent: event)
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    if let touch = touches.first{
        print("\(touch)")
    }
    super.touchesMoved(touches, withEvent: event)
}
```

Comment: I can't build the project. Getting error *Method does not override any method from its superclass* for the `touchesBegan` function. I tried to subclass from `UIGestureRecognizer` and `UTapGestureRecognizer`. Xcode 7.1

Comment: use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30892254/override-func-error-in-swift-2 to check what going on with your code

Answer (score 10):

Using **Swift 3** and **Xcode 8**

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

}

override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>?, with event: UIEvent?) {
// Don't forget to add "?" after Set<UITouch>
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It is now in the Apple API reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesBegan:withEvent:) and for overriding in xCode version 6.3 and swift 1.2 you can use this code:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    if let touch =  touches.first as? UITouch {
         // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Interesting that the online docs are correct but the version included in the Xcode help system is out-of-date. I guess I need to get in the habit of searching for this stuff online.

Answer (score 6):

The current one right now for the newest update as of xCode 7.2 Swift 2.1 on Dec 19, 2015.

Next time you get an error like this again, remove the function and start typing it again "touchesBe..." and xCode should automatically complete it to the newest one for you instead of trying to fix the old one.

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch: AnyObject! in touches {
        let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)

        //Use touchLocation for example: button.containsPoint(touchLocation) meaning the user has pressed the button.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was:

```
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {
            // ...
        }

        super.touchesBegan(touches , withEvent:event!)
    }
```

Comment: If you are on Xcode 6.3 and Swift 1.2 your code will not work. This post if referencing Xcode 6.3 and Swift 1.2.

Comment: You are right, I updated Xcode today and it immediately gave error.

Answer (score 4):

Small addition. For swift to compile w/o error, you need to add

import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass

Answer (score 1):

Using **Swift 4** and **Xcode 9**

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {

            if touch.view == self.view{
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add comments, explain your answer, read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).