# Confusing compile error trying to upgrade to Swift 1.2

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swift

I've been able to update my code for XCode 6.3 and Swift 1.2 without much issue, until I tried to fix my overridden touch input functions from UIHandler. I updated the signature of all four touch functions to the following:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
    ...
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesMoved(touches, withEvent: event)
    ...
}
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    ...
}
override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<NSObject>!, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    ...
}
```

XCode's autocomplete actually suggests these methods/signatures when I go to write them, so I know that XCode recognizes Swift 1.2. However, when I clean and build, I get "Method does not override any method from its superclass" for all four functions, as well as similar errors when calling the "super" versions of those functions.

I haven't found anything in project/build settings that stands out, and I tried clearing the DerivedData folder as well as restarting my computer, but I'm still getting these errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I was hitting the EXACT same error messages as you were, and it was driving me crazy. I finally figured out what the problem was ... and if you had followed the same tutorial online I did, it might have gotten you as well.

Turns out I had a swift file called Set.swift ... that defined a class called Set.

But now in Swift 1.2, they introduced their own class called Set, so my class was causing collisions and these errors whereever I used Set<> (mostly in the touchesXXX part, but there was one other spot in the code where I used Set, and that's what clued me in).  So I just went into the Set.swift, and renamed the class to something else, and then it all started compiling correctly.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yep, I had that too! I bet this was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try completely cleaning the project (CMD + ALT + SHIFT + K)?

I had to do that in mine to get it to compile.

Comment: Yep! It didn't fix the problem.

Comment: What class are you trying to override?  I will test it on my end.

Comment: I'm overriding SKScene.

Comment: Yeah, no problems with that on my end.   
First, command click the super.touchesbegan to see if SKScene is indeed updated. 

If it is, then create a duplicate of your SKScene file with a new class name just to see if your project is not compiling the one file  correctly

Answer (score 0):

Super function call have to be at the end:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    \\ Your code


    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, but that wouldn't cause the compile errors would it?

Comment: @heyx3 I did it and I don't have errors. Did you try it?

Comment: Not yet; can't really try things again until Monday.

Comment: no it does not, that is terrible advice that deserves a downvote