# touchesBegan and touchesEnded not called on a UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiresponder

When I touch a `UIButton`, the `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved` and `touchesEnded` methods are not called. I want to perform an event when a continuous touch happens and cancel the event when the touch ends.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [touchesbegan/moved/ended not working with xcode 6.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29552897/touchesbegan-moved-ended-not-working-with-xcode-6-3)

Comment: Check `userInteractionEnabled` is set to true on the button and all its superviews. It is by default true for most `UIViews`, but there are some exceptions.

Comment: For uibutton this is not called

Comment: Did you set it's `delegate`?

Answer (score 0):

You can track UIButton touch start and touch end by using UIButton control events.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(touchStarted:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(touchEnded:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(touchEnded:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
}


- (void)touchStarted:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Touch started");
}

- (void)touchEnded:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Touch ended");
}
```