# Swift Error- Use of Undeclared Type

Tags: ios, swift

I am building a replica of "Space Invaders" in Swift. The error I am getting:

> Use of Undeclared Type 'Set'

The following is a sample of my code:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = touches.first as UITouch
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
    let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)
    if(touchedNode.name == "startgame"){
        let gameOverScene = GameScene(size: size)
        gameOverScene.scaleMode = scaleMode
        let transitionType = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(1.0)
        view?.presentScene(gameOverScene,transition: transitionType)
    }
}
```

and:

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set <NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */
    for touch in (touches as Set<UITouch>) {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")

        sprite.xScale = 0.5
        sprite.yScale = 0.5
        sprite.position = location

        let action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI), duration:1)

        sprite.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))

        self.addChild(sprite)
    }
}
```

In both cases the error occurs at: `(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent)`

Can someone please suggest a possible solution?

Comment: What specific version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Version 6.2 (6C131e)

Comment: Upgrade Xcode to 6.3 or 6.4... `Set` was not introduced until Swift 1.2, which came in Xcode 6.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are updated your code with new version of swift.

This code was for older versions :

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
}
```

> Set introduced in Swift 1.2

From Xcode 6.3.2 version :

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
    var touch : UITouch = (touches.first as? UITouch)!

}
```

From Xcode 7 (Source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28772136/3202193):

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        // ...
    }
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent:event)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the xCode version. If you are using xCode 6.3 or xCode 6.4, that means you are on Swift 1.2 then code must be like below:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = touches.first as UITouch
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
    let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)
    if(touchedNode.name == "startgame"){
        let gameOverScene = GameScene(size: size)
        gameOverScene.scaleMode = scaleMode
        let transitionType = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(1.0)
        view?.presentScene(gameOverScene,transition: transitionType)
    }
}
```

If you are on xCode 6.2, that means you are using Swift 1.1 and the code should be like below:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        let touch = touches.first as UITouch
        let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)
        if(touchedNode.name == "startgame"){
            let gameOverScene = GameScene(size: size)
            gameOverScene.scaleMode = scaleMode
            let transitionType = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(1.0)
            view?.presentScene(gameOverScene,transition: transitionType)
        }
    }
```

Please note that `Set` is introduced in Swift 1.2.

Hope this will help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade Xcode to 6.3 or 6.4... `Set` was not introduced until Swift 1.2, which came in Xcode 6.3.

That is why Xcode is telling you:

> Use of Undeclared Type 'Set'

It does not exist in Xcode 6.2