# How to set a tap for imageview array in Swift/Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7-beta3

I am trying to set tap listeners for each imageview from my imageview array and print when one is selected. Ideally I would like each imageview to have its on listener - such as "imageview 2 was selected." Thanks!

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

var index: Int = 0

var images: [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "image1.png")!, UIImage(named: "image2.png")!, UIImage(named: "image3.png")!, UIImage(named: "image4.png")!, UIImage(named: "image5.png")!, UIImage(named: "image6.png")!, UIImage(named: "image7.png")!, UIImage(named: "image8.png")!, UIImage(named: "image9.png")!, UIImage(named: "image10.png")!, UIImage(named: "image11.png")!, UIImage(named: "image12.png")!, UIImage(named: "image13.png")!, UIImage(named: "image14.png")!, UIImage(named: "image15.png")!, UIImage(named: "image16.png")!, UIImage(named: "image17.png")!, UIImage(named: "image18.png")!, UIImage(named: "image19.png")!, UIImage(named: "image20.png")!, UIImage(named: "image21.png")!, UIImage(named: "image22.png")!, UIImage(named: "image23.png")!, UIImage(named: "image24.png")!, UIImage(named: "image25.png")!, UIImage(named: "image26.png")!, UIImage(named: "image27.png")!, UIImage(named: "image28.png")!, UIImage(named: "image29.png")!, UIImage(named: "image30.png")!]

var imageView: [UIImageView] = []



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let screenWidth = screenSize.width
    //let screenHeight = screenSize.height

    let numWidth: CGFloat = 3
    let numHeight: CGFloat = 10
    self.scrollView.frame.size.width = screenWidth
    let width: CGFloat = (self.scrollView.frame.size.width - (numWidth + 1))/3

    var tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("tappedMe"))

    for var i:CGFloat = 0; i < 3; ++i{
        for var j:CGFloat = 0; j < 10; ++j {

            let image: UIImage = images[index]
            imageView.append(UIImageView(image: image))
            imageView[index].frame = CGRectMake(width*i, width*j, width, width)
            self.scrollView.addSubview(imageView[index])

            imageView[index].addGestureRecognizer(tap)
            imageView[index].userInteractionEnabled = true

            index++
        }
    }
    scrollView.contentSize.height = (width)*numHeight


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func imageTapped(img: AnyObject)
{
    // Your action
    print("tapped")
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use custom class instead of holding array of UIImageView.

```
 import UIKit 
 class MyCustomImageView : UIImageView{

    var myId : String = "";
    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame);
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        println("IM TOUCHED\(myId)");
    }
}
```

.
.
.

```
var imageView: [MyCustomImageView] = []
```

and in your loop:

```
  for var i:CGFloat = 0; i < 3; ++i{
        for var j:CGFloat = 0; j < 10; ++j {

            let image: UIImage = images[index]
            imageView.append(MyCustomImageView(frame:  CGRectMake(width*i, width*j, width, width)))

            imageView[index].image = image;
            self.scrollView.addSubview(imageView[index])

            imageView[index].myId = "Image number \(index)";


            index++
        }
    }
```

and btw, dont know what are you trying to do with all width height,
but this is a bit more clear way:

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    let imageIndex : (begin:Int,end:Int) = (begin:1,end:30);
    var imageView: [MyCustomImageView] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        let screenWidth = screenSize.width
        //let screenHeight = screenSize.height

        let numWidth: CGFloat = 3
        let numHeight: CGFloat = 10
        self.scrollView.frame.size.width = screenWidth
        let width: CGFloat = (self.scrollView.frame.size.width - (numWidth + 1))/3
        var index = self.imageIndex.begin;

        for var i:CGFloat = 0; i < 3; ++i{
            for var j:CGFloat = 0; j < 10; ++j {

                let image: UIImage? = UIImage(named: "image\(index++).png");
                var currentImageView = MyCustomImageView(frame: CGRectMake(width*i, width*j, width, width))
                currentImageView.image = image;
                currentImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
                currentImageView.myId = "image\(index++).png";
                self.scrollView.addSubview(imageView[index])
                imageView.append(currentImageView);
            }
        }
        scrollView.contentSize.height = (width)*numHeight


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: In the touchesBegan method, Swift is giving the issue: "method does not override any method from its superclass" Thanks

Comment: make sure you added import UIKit in the class file

Comment: Oh I think this is because you are using objective c. I found the equivalent method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28771896/overriding-method-with-selector-touchesbeganwithevent-has-incompatible-type

Comment: nope, using swift. just write func touch began and let xCode autocomplete and override and make sure you write in in MyCustomView class and NOT in UIViewController :)

Comment: Note I am using Swift 2 with the latest Xcode 7 beta 3

Comment: can you post a comment with your code? + try to write func touchBe and let xCode autocomplete

Comment: Ok it autcompleted to: override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        print("IM TOUCHED\(myId)");
    }

Comment: There are no errors but it does not detect the touches :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83620/discussion-between-daniel-krom-and-user190494).

Comment: Adding "imageView[index]. userInteractionEnabled = true" solved the issue