# Swift 2 version of this if statement

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2, uipangesturerecognizer

Getting an error saying `NSSet` does not have a member named first for this `if` statement

```
if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {
}
```

Comment: The error should be self explaining?

Comment: `NSSet` indeed does not have  a member named first, but the Swift type `Set` has

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28771896/overriding-method-with-selector-touchesbeganwithevent-has-incompatible-type

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong, it should be:

```
if let touches = touches.first as UITouch! { 
}
```

Comment: im still getting an error that says NSSet does not have a member named first