# Method does not override any method from it's superclass

Tags: swift, touchesbegan, touchesmoved

I'm trying to create a new override func when i got this error:  Method does not override any method from it's superclass

I have already tried to delete the  override  part but that only gives me another error.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {

    let touch : UITouch! = touches.anyObject() as! UITouch

    location = touch.locationInView(self.view)

    person.center = location
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {

    let touch : UITouch! = touches.anyObject() as! UITouch

    location = touch.locationInView(self.view)

    person.center = location

}
```

Comment: And the other error is...? Also, what is the type of the object this method is in?

Comment: Different error message, but same problem as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28771896/overriding-method-with-selector-touchesbeganwithevent-has-incompatible-type.

Answer (score 5):

The correct method signatures are:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

}
```