# Method does not override any method from its superclass for Set<NSObject>

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

I was looking at a project that I made in Swift 1 a few years ago. And I noticed an error after converting my code to Swift 3 syntax that said `Method does not override any method from its superclass`. I know its because the Set is old syntax but what do I replace it with? This is the line:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<NSObject>, with event: UIEvent) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: It's now `Set<UITouch>`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26811892/1271826

Comment: Code for all Swift versions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28771896/overriding-method-with-selector-touchesbeganwithevent-has-incompatible-type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method in Swift 3 has change to:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
}
```

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621142-touchesbegan) from Apple

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3**

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```